# Check if within Div area onclick event

Tags: html, onclick, jscript

I have a pop up menu that appears when the users name is hovered over using onmouseeneter and the menu disapeers when onmouseleave is triggerd.

The problem i have is that on occasion the mouseleave is not triggered and the menu stays showing, which is ok but i require another check to see if mouse is within the div on mouse move. and also a click event to close the div if the click is outside of the div.

How can i check weather a click or a mousemove is within a div or not.

I have tried the following with no luck. allthough the code is fine i require another way.

```
<div id='overlay' class='overlay' style='display:none;' 
onmouseover='showoverlay();' onmouseleave='removeoverlay();'> </div>


function showoverlay() {
    var overlay=document.getElementById("overlay"); 
    overlay.style.display="block";
    overlay.style.zIndex="999";     
    overlay.style.opacity="1";

}

function removeoverlay() {

    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    overlay.style.opacity="0";
    overlay.style.display="none"
    overlay.style.zIndex="-999";                

}


$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).mouse(function(e)
    {
      var subject = $("#overlay"); 

        if(e.target.id != subject.attr('id') && 
        !subject.has(e.target).length)
       {
        removeoverlay();
       }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) jQuery function like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul').on('click', function (event) {
        let target = $(event.target);
        let handle = $(this).find('i');
        let checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');

        if (false === target.is(handle) && false === target.is(checkbox)) {
            checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks il giv it a try. only problem is that iv not used un-orderd list. its a custom menu. but il work around it. as long as theres meat on the bone il sort it, thanks

Comment: you deleted your last question too quickly for me to say you could keep it strict by casting everything to int: https://3v4l.org/Yvs0e